# Создание Collection с reflection Type

Tags: java, коллекции, рефлексия

Есть метод, который возвращает List< String > (возможен любой объект), но я не знаю об этом и выясняю тип следующим способом:

```
Type returnType = ((ParameterizedType)entry.getGenericReturnType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Потом я хочу создать TypeReference, в котором будет Collection, но я не могу, пишет : "can not fynd symbol".

```
TypeReference typeReference = new TypeReference<Collection<returnType>>() { };
```

Этот референс нужен для получения объектов из файла что бы jackson преобразовал данные в массив нужных мне объектов.

```
final File file = new File(path);
FileUtils.createFileWithParentDir(file);
FileUtils.createAndFillIfMissingOrEmpty(file, Collections.singletonList("[]"));
data = objectMapper.readValue(file, typeReference);
```

Как мне создать Collection по подобию уже существующего метода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй использовать метод [Objectmapper.#getTypeFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#getTypeFactory()). Примерно так

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
Type returnType = ((ParameterizedType)entry.getGenericReturnType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
List<Object> someClassList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, (Class)returnType));
```

Обрати внимание, что объявление `someClassList` не содержит явного типа, однако все объекты в коллекции будут фактически иметь нужный тебе тип.

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7246510/5506820)

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать генерацию класса по имени и Generic Method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = A.class.getDeclaredMethod("a");
        Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();

        Class clazz = Class.forName(returnType.getTypeName());
        TypeReference typeReference = createTypeReference(clazz);
    }

    static <T> TypeReference<Collection<T>> createTypeReference(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new TypeReference<Collection<T>>() {
        };
    }
```

Comment: а почему не java.util.Collection<String> в выводе?

Comment: Сообразить не могу, как этот метод приспособить что бы возвращал референс? Что бы в main его продолжать использовать.

Comment: Исправил код для наглядности

Comment: По идее в ActualTypeArguments должен быть мой класс когда я дебажу и создаю референс. Этот референс нужен был для чтения с файла. Но  класса, который мы передавали я не вижу... Все объекты считались как HashMap, поидее должны были преобразоваться к классу.

Comment: T определяется как Object, а не класс который мы передали.

Comment: скинь больше кода

Comment: В описании добавил код. Написал, что я с референсом делаю и зачем.